# GLib-GIO-Message al correr python script

Tags: python

Al correr un script en python obtengo el siguiente error:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

No tengo idea de qué se trata y cómo solucionarlo.

Nota: El programa se ejecuta correctamente y hace lo que tiene que hacer.

Espero puedan ayudarme,

Lucía

Comment: Hola @Lucia, normalmente deberías pegar el Script a la pregunta para poder hacer algún diagnóstico, sin embargo parece que tu problema es mas de sistema operativo que de Python, se sugiero estos enlaces [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins), [2](https://lavidaestux.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/como-solucionar-el-error-glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend/)

Comment: Gracias! Parece que efectivamente es un problema del SO, no entiendo nada de lo que explican esos post la verdad... puedo probar las soluciones propuestas, pero sin entender realmente...

Answer (score 0):

la Aplicación que estas usando/importando Glib-GIO-Message y por alguna razón esta almacenando la información en memoria y no en la configuración del sistema

checa si instalando "dconf" se remueve ese warning.

apt-get install dconf

Comment: obtengo el siguiente error:                                                                                  `:~$ sudo apt-get install dconf
[sudo] password for lucia: 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete dconf no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

E: El paquete «dconf» no tiene un candidato para la instalación`